# Got stuck at verifying path of file exist (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently learning python and I have hit a stumbling block. I have found the absolute and relative path of a file, spam.txt but whenever I used os.path.exists to verify that the file spam.txt exists, it keeps returning false. What am I doing wrong?

```
>>> os.path.abspath('spam.txt')

'C:\\spam.txt'
>>> os.path.relpath('spam.txt')

'spam.txt'
>>> os.path.isfile('spam.txt')

False
>>> os.path.isfile('C:\\spam.txt')

False
>>> 

>>> os.path.isabs('C:\\spam.txt')

True
>>> os.path.exists('C:\\spam.txt')

False
>>> os.path.exists('spam.txt')

False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give complete path in the arguments, not just the file name if your file is at a different location than your script.

```
os.path.exists('/home/user/spam.txt')
os.path.exists('C:\spam.txt') or os.path.exists('C:\spam.txt')
```

Tested on linux.
Not tested on windows, but should work

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you are running the python and any script in a location (current working directory) where there is no file named `spam.txt`, and also that there is no file named `spam.txt` at `C:\\spam.txt`. I assume this is on Windows.
Also try:

```
os.getcwd()
```

or move the file to C-drive's root.